# an estimate for derivative

Tags: calculus, analysis, differential-geometry

let $F$ a closed convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, let $x,y\in F$ and assume that for any $s\in[0,1]$ we have 
$f(s):=\mid sx+(1-s)y-z\mid\geq \mid y-z\mid$
why is it true that $\frac{\partial}{\partial s} f(s) |_{s=0}\geq 0$?

Comment: Maybe because $f(s)\ge f(0)$ for every $s\ge0$?

Comment: What is $z$ in your expression?

Answer (score 1):

$g(s):=\left(f(s)-|y-z|\right)\ge0$  for $s\ge0 $ and $g(0)=0$ so the minimum of $g$ happens at $s=0.$ Therefore, after $s=0$, $g$  increases; that's why the derivative must be non-negative.